# Under what circumstances would there be only a .jar file but no .pom file?

Tags: java, maven

When using the company's internal Maven repository, I get an error when compiling a local project: `Could not find artifact org.apache:axis2:pom:1.7.8`

I find that the axis2.jar file exists in org.apache:axis2, but the axis2.pom file does not exist.

It's really confusing. Under what circumstances might that happen?

Is this something wrong which need the department that maintains the Maven repository to fix?

Comment: If there is no corrosponding `.pom` file there is something broken but the above shows that you have define the wrong groupId: `org.apache` (https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:org.apache%20a:axis2)  instead of `org.apache.axis2` https://search.maven.org/search?q=org.apache.axis2